# How to I get a value to change if a certain button is pressed in tkinter using classes with multiple commands

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a quiz game and am trying to get the score to update when the correct button is pressed. There is currently a loop that makes 4 buttons with answers but I need to assign a function/command which adds to the score if the button with the right answer is correct. How would I go about trying to achieve this? Do I make each individual button and just assign the right command to the right answer or is there a more efficient way?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox




score = 0
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainMenu)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Maths Picture/Button
        global photo
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #configure = tk.Frame(self)
        #configure.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #configure.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "MathsPicture.png")
        photoimage = photo.subsample(3,3)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="MainMenu", font=('Verdana', 40, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)
        button = tk.Button(self, image = photo, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(PageOne), ScoreUpdate()])
        button.grid(row=1, column=1)
        #tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two",command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(PageTwo), ScoreUpdate()]).pack()
        
def ScoreUpdate(event=None):
    global score
    score += 500



x = open("MathsQuestions.txt", "r", errors = "ignore")
MathsQuestions = x.read()
MathsQ = MathsQuestions.split(",")
x.close()

#symbols
#r = row
#q = question
#a = answer

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    global score
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 1
        r = 3
        q = 0
        y = 0
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=score , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q1/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        #lbl = tk.Label(self, text="What is something plus 10-", font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        #btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go back to Main Menu", font=('Helvetica', 20), command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu))
        #btn.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan= 1)
        for i in range(4):
            btny = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo))
            btny.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
            y = y + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 6
        r = 3
        q = 5
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=score , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q1/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        #lbl = tk.Label(self, text="What is something plus 10-", font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        #btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go back to Main Menu", font=('Helvetica', 20), command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu))
        #btn.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan= 1)
        for i in range(4):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageThree))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        #btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two",command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(PageTwo), ScoreUpdate()])
        #btn.grid(row=5,column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")

class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 6
        r = 3
        q = 5
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=score , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q1/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        #lbl = tk.Label(self, text="What is something plus 10-", font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        #btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go back to Main Menu", font=('Helvetica', 20), command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu))
        #btn.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan= 1)
        for i in range(4):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageThree))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        #btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two",command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(PageTwo), ScoreUpdate()])
        #btn.grid(row=5,column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = SampleApp()
    window.geometry("1000x900")

    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave isn't complete, but lets address the question -
Each time you press a button, you can save the given answer and then compare it to the right one. It can be a global function that gets the question/question number and the given answer and returns True/False or the updated score.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is simple here is sample code on how you can implement such thing (the code is not the best but it works (I made it a while ago))(have questions? ask them):

```
answer_number = 0
score = 0
task_num = 0

task_list = [task1, task2, task3, task4, task5, task6, task7, task8, task9, task10, task10]
task_answers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
task_place = task_list[task_num - 1]

def next_task(task_number, number):
    global my_label
    global finish_button
    global ans1
    global ans2
    global ans3
    global answer_number
    global task_num
    global task_answers
    global task_place
    global score

    answer_number = number

    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(image=task_list[task_number - 1])
    my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    ans1.grid_forget()
    ans2.grid_forget()
    ans3.grid_forget()

    ans1 = Button(root, text="               1               ", width="10", command=lambda: next_task(task_number + 1, 1))
    ans2 = Button(root, text="               2               ", width="10", command=lambda: next_task(task_number + 1, 2))
    ans3 = Button(root, text="               3               ", width="10", command=lambda: next_task(task_number + 1, 3))

    ans1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ans2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    ans3.grid(row=1, column=2)

    if task_number == 11:
        finish()

    task_num = task_number - 1

    if answer_number == task_answers[task_num - 1]:
        score += 10
    else:
        pass
```

as I said it is a dum-dum code but it works and it is important that you understand the concept (obviously there is more than one) also notice what function the buttons call